# I am having trouble to show all data from two different tables which are having different records

Tags: php, html, database, codeigniter

For information in using codeigniter

I have two tables:

> 1. table A has 4 records    [picture 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nsy1A.jpg)
> 2. table B has 5 records    [picutre 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pJ9vv.jpg)

I want to show that records from 2 tables I have above to my view
but in my view, it just shows 4 records.

1. 4 records from table A
2. 4 records from table B

Even though in table B has 5 records it just shows 4 records

This is my code :

Model

```
function getAlldata(){
   $this->db->select('*');
   $this->db->from('data_skm_organisasi'); 
   $this->db- >JOIN('data_skm_kejuaraan','data_skm_kejuaraan.id=data_skm_organisasi.id');
   $results = $this->db->get();     
   return $results->result();
}
```

controller

```
public function V_home()
{
   $dataSimpanOrganisasi = array();
   $dataSimpanOrganisasi ['organisasi']= $this->M_main->getAlldata(); ;
   $this->load->view('V_mahasiswa',$dataSimpanOrganisasi);
}
```

view

```
<?php foreach ($organisasi as $dataSimpan) { ?>
     <div>
          <?php echo $dataSimpan->Lembaga; ?>
          <?php echo $dataSimpan->tingkatan_O; ?><br><br>
     </div>
          <?php } 
?><br><br>

<?php foreach ($organisasi as $dataSimpan) { ?>
      <div>
          <?php echo $dataSimpan->jenisKegiatan; ?>
          <?php echo $dataSimpan->tingkatan; ?><br><br>
      </div>
          <?php } 
?>
```

what should I do to my code? is there is any problem in my code?

Answer (score 0):

You are using an normal `$db->join` command, which is an inner join. This is why you only see the rows of table B, when there is a corredsponding row in table A. In your case, it seems you need an outer join, not an inner join. you can specify it by adding a parameter to your join statement:

```
$this->db->join('data_skm_kejuaraan', 'data_skm_kejuaraan.id=data_skm_organisasi.id', 'right outer');
```

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'OUTER JOIN `data_skm_kejuaraan` ON `data_skm_kejuaraan`.`id`=`data_skm_organisas' at line 3

SELECT * FROM `data_skm_organisasi` OUTER JOIN `data_skm_kejuaraan` ON `data_skm_kejuaraan`.`id`=`data_skm_organisasi`.`id`

Comment: That's odd... try to just add an additional parameter `'outer'` to your query, and don't change anything else in the code... That can't break it...

Comment: but when i try using  `'right outer'` it works, but its doesnt work with `'outer'`in my query

Comment: Ok, great! seems the normal 'outer' is not supported by MariaDB, that's why you need to use 'right outer'. I adjusted my answer. Would be nice if you consider accepting/upvoting my answer, if it helped you solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think you used the wrong column to join on the `data_skm_kejuaraan` table. Try change :

```
$this->db->JOIN('data_skm_kejuaraan','data_skm_kejuaraan.id=data_skm_organisasi.id');
```

to

```
$this->db->JOIN('data_skm_kejuaraan','data_skm_kejuaraan.id_juara=data_skm_organisasi.id');
```

Comment: thanks for your answer,, my problem is already solved.. 

but another problem is mariaDB server version doesnt support full outer